# Relation between Kafka Consumer Rate and Producer Rate (in context of Kafka Lag)?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, producer-consumer

I'm running an application where I often observe lot of lag in the Kafka consumer. I do have basic understanding that the lag is caused when the consumer is not able to consume the messages as fast as the producer is producing. In my case, I observe that the main reason for the increased Lag is because the **consumer rate is gradually dropping along with the producer rate.**

**For example :**
Producer starts with 10k rpm, the consumer is initially consuming at 8k rpm ( some lag ). But as the producer rate starts to drop (say 6k rpm), I expected consumer to still run at 8k rpm to cover up the existing lag, but instead the consumer rate also drops gradually ( say 3k rpm )as a result, lag is increasing exponentially and the whole messages are consumed at lower rate.

**Question :**

1. Does the consumer rate somehow depend on rate at which messages are being produced ? ( Because this is the trend that i observed )
2. Is there a way to reduce this kind of lag by maintaining consistent consumer rate ? ( Increasing partitions did help in achieving more tps at peaks, but didn't make much difference in decreasing rate case)
3. Is there any app properties that I should be configuring in my Spring Application that can help in this case ?

**Note :** Kindly mention if i need to be specific in any points.

Comment: The consumer should be decoupled completely from the producer. It's not natural for their rates to adjust in relation each other

Comment: Are there multiple consumer instances? Look at their rates individually and see if there are outliers. What can happen is messages distributed unevenly between partitions, with one  partition overloaded while others are mostly idle. This could bring down the aggregate average rate (because most consumers have little to consume) while still introducing lag (because the overloaded consumer can’t keep up).

Comment: @TimMoore According to my previous analysis, i did observe the lag distributed over all the partitions more or less equally. Will check it again..

Comment: @TimMoore , I see that the distribution of lag is almost equal in all the partitions. Do you have anything else to suggest ?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Do u have any idea what i can debug to get more clarity on whats affecting the consumer rate ?

Comment: CPU/network IO could affect the rates, but I wouldn't think it's that significant. You'll need other tools to monitor that

Comment: @OneCricketeer The CPU Usage is generally too high (> 300% at peaks consistently), I monitor it on grafana.. Do you suggest me to look into any other data points and reduce the CPU usage ?

Comment: Without knowing how you've setup any JVM threads, hard to say if that is high or not